# How to troubleshoot an "AttributeError: __exit__" in multiproccesing in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pool

I tried to rewrite some csv-reading code to be able to run it on multiple cores in Python 3.2.2. I tried to use the `Pool` object of multiprocessing, which I adapted from working examples (and already worked for me for another part of my project). I ran into an error message I found hard to decipher and troubleshoot.

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parser5_nodots_parallel.py", line 256, in <module>
    MG,ppl = csv2graph(r)
  File "parser5_nodots_parallel.py", line 245, in csv2graph
    node_chunks)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 552, in get
    raise self._value
AttributeError: __exit__
```

The relevant code:

```
import csv
import time
import datetime
import re
from operator import itemgetter
from multiprocessing import Pool
import itertools

def chunks(l,n):
    """Divide a list of nodes `l` in `n` chunks"""
    l_c = iter(l)
    while 1:
        x = tuple(itertools.islice(l_c,n))
        if not x:
            return
        yield x

def csv2nodes(r):
    strptime = time.strptime
    mktime = time.mktime
    l = []
    ppl = set()
    pattern = re.compile(r"""[A-Za-z0-9"/]+?(?=[,\n])""")
    for row in r:
        with pattern.findall(row) as f:
            cell = int(f[3])
            id = int(f[2])
            st = mktime(strptime(f[0],'%d/%m/%Y'))
            ed = mktime(strptime(f[1],'%d/%m/%Y'))
        # collect list
        l.append([(id,cell,{1:st,2: ed})])
        # collect separate sets
        ppl.add(id)
    return (l,ppl)

def csv2graph(source):
    MG=nx.MultiGraph()
    # Remember that I use integers for edge attributes, to save space! Dic above.
    # start: 1
    # end: 2
    p = Pool()
    node_divisor = len(p._pool)
    node_chunks = list(chunks(source,int(len(source)/int(node_divisor))))
    num_chunks = len(node_chunks)
    pedgelists = p.map(csv2nodes,
                       node_chunks)
    ll = []
    ppl = set()
    for l in pedgelists:
        ll.append(l[0])
        ppl.update(l[1])
    MG.add_edges_from(ll)
    return (MG,ppl)

with open('/Users/laszlosandor/Dropbox/peers_prisons/python/codetenus_test.txt','r') as source:
    r = source.readlines()
    MG,ppl = csv2graph(r)
```

What's a good way to troubleshoot this?

Comment: In my case, i was accidentally passing a `None` due to scoping issues.

Comment: I had this when I was declaring a class as `Class SomeClass(object):` even though I DID explicitly have an __exit__ in my class. Once I removed the inheritance from `object` it worked. I have no idea why, so YMMV

Answer (score 162, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
with pattern.findall(row) as f:
```

You are using the `with` statement. It requires an object with `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods. But `pattern.findall` returns a `list`, `with` tries to store the `__exit__` method, but it can't find it, and raises an error. Just use

```
f = pattern.findall(row)
```

instead.

Answer (score 66):

It is not the asker's problem in this instance but **the first** troubleshooting step for a generic "AttributeError: __exit__" should be making sure the brackets are there, e.g.

```
with SomeContextManager() as foo:
    #works because a new object is referenced...
```

**not**

```
with SomeContextManager as foo:
    #AttributeError because the class is referenced
```

Catches me out from time to time and I end up here -__-

Answer (score 9):

The error also happens when trying to use the

```
with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
   # ...
```

with a Python version that is too old (like Python 2.X) and does not support using `with` together with multiprocessing pools.

(See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25968716/1426569 to another question for more details)

Comment: Yep! Working great on Python 3.X

Answer (score -2):

The reason behind this error is : 
Flask app is already running, hasn't shut down and in middle of that we try to start another instance by:
with app.app_context():
     #Code
Before we use this with statement we need to make sure that scope of the previous running app is closed.