# Python Multiprocessing Lib Error (AttributeError: __exit__)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle, with-statement, contextmanager

Am getting this error when using the `pool.map(funct, iterable)`:

```
AttributeError: __exit__
```

No Explanation, only stack trace to the pool.py file within the module.

using in this way:

```
with Pool(processes=2) as pool:
   pool.map(myFunction, mylist)
   pool.map(myfunction2, mylist2)
```

I suspect there could be a problem with the picklability (python needs to `pickle`, or transform list data into byte stream) yet I'm not sure if this is true or if it is how to debug.

EDIT: new format of code that produces this error :

```
def governingFunct(list):
    #some tasks
    def myFunction():
         # function contents
    with closing(Pool(processes=2)) as pool:
         pool.map(myFunction, sublist)
         pool.map(myFunction2, sublist2)
```

ERROR PRODUCED:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
```

Comment: what do you mean by `while .. as`? did you mean `with`?

Comment: Do include the *full traceback* for errors, and your actual code. `while` is an obvious syntax error here, for example, but from the exception it is clear you used `with` really.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

In Python 2.x and 3.0, 3.1 and 3.2, `multiprocessing.Pool()` objects are *not context managers*. You cannot use them in a `with` statement. Only in Python 3.3 and up can you use them as such. From the [Python 3 `multiprocessing.Pool()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool):

> *New in version 3.3*: Pool objects now support the context management protocol – see Context Manager Types. `__enter__()` returns the pool object, and `__exit__()` calls terminate().

For earlier Python versions, you could use [`contextlib.closing()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing), but take into account this'll call *`pool.close()`*, not `pool.terminate()`. Terminate manually in that case:

```
from contextlib import closing

with closing(Pool(processes=2)) as pool:
    pool.map(myFunction, mylist)
    pool.map(myfunction2, mylist2)
    pool.terminate()
```

or create your own `terminating()` context manager:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def terminating(thing):
    try:
        yield thing
    finally:
        thing.terminate()

with terminating(Pool(processes=2)) as pool:
    pool.map(myFunction, mylist)
    pool.map(myfunction2, mylist2)
```

Comment: Well Sir thank you for such a detailed explanation. You're solution has moved the function a step closer to working - now I am getting this error:

`PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed`

Comment: @sidewaiise: are you trying to use a method on a class perhaps? See [Multiprocessing: using Pool.map on a function defined in a class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3288595)

Comment: Heh I was actually just reading that as you posted this. Thanks - I'll have a read and comment shortly.

Comment: Not sure I understand the solution on that link - I'm not using classes. It's as simple as I wrote above, except that it is inside another function.... eg:

**** Refer to Edited Question ^ ****

So not sure.. any ideas?

Comment: @sidewaiise: functions nested in another function are not picklable. Normally, pickle will store just a name (*`modulename.functionname`*) then import the same function on the other side. You cannot do that when you need to call another function to get the function.

Comment: Getting there... new error: `IndexError: string index out of range`. Again no explanation on where the error actually occurs.

Comment: (I've taken the Pool method out of the original function also)

Comment: If you have new problems, better ask a new question. Your original issue here has been solved after all, and we now have a nice question + answer that'll perhaps others in future. No need to muddle this with new, different problems.

Comment: True. Have done just now actually, thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25974256/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-throws-exception-indexerror-string-index-out

Comment: Excuse me, but when I'm creating my own "terminating" do I have to do `from contextlib import contextmanager` ?

Comment: @paulochf: for some reason the decorator line was missing. Only import it when you actually plan on using it! :-) (and *sorry*).

Answer (score 1):

`with` statement is for object that have `__enter__` and `__exit__` functions, i.e.  [Context Manager Types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager)
`multiprocessing.Pool` is not Context Manager Type.
try do the following:

```
pool = Pool(processes=2)
pool.map(myFunction, mylist)
pool.map(myfunction2, mylist2)
```

Comment: The question is *why the OP thought it was*. The answer is that the Python 3 documentation tells you it is. But it also qualifies that as Python 3.3 and up.