# How to debug Python Multiprocessing pool.map() error (IndexError: string index out of range) without a stack trace?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Using pool.map() from multiprocessing lib in python. Get the following error:

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Is this likely from a variable (list) which is out of range? if so how can I debug it? There's no explanation of where the error occured.

More explanation of code:

(EDIT)

```
def myFunction(list):
     # function contents
     for item in list:
          # do tasks
with closing(Pool(processes=2)) as pool:
     pool.map(myFunction, sublist)
     pool.map(myFunction2, sublist2)
```

Comment: Can you give us a *short reproducible sample* that demonstrates the exception? Without it all we can do is speculate.

Comment: The exception is probably being thrown inside `myFunction` or `myFunction2`. Prior to Python 3.3 exception thrown inside worker processes didn't show a proper backtrace, instead, you'd just see a trace coming from the `pool.map` call itself. Can you include the full `Traceback`? You should also try wrapping all of `myFunction` and `myFunction2` in a `try`/`except` block, and then using `import traceback ; traceback.print_exc()` to so you can see what the real Traceback is.

Comment: I have some `for item in list` loops in `myFunction` which I think are broken... I'm working with a lot of variables so will take me some time today to go through it, but thanks for your traceback suggestion, i might implement that to make it easier to debug :) will post solution if im able.

Comment: @dano if you want to write that as a solution, it could be the best way to debug the issue (which is basically what my question was). thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer lays in my misunderstanding of the `pool.map(func, iterable)` method.

The previous function `myFunction()` used a for loop to cycle through the list object. I had left this in the function after implementing `pool.map()` so all the tasks which i had carefully prepared were going another level deeper due to the `for` loop.

The solution was a simple case of removing the for loop and adjusting some of the code to look more like this:

```
def myFunction(list):
    # do tasks
    # for loop contents....
```

So much simpler, however I did not realise how the `.map()` method should be used in teh first place. Thanks @dano for pointing out what needed to be looked at.