# multiprocessing pool hangs in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing

I have a very simple script which is the following:

```
import multiprocessing as multi

def call_other_thing_with_multi():
    P = multi.Pool(3)
    P.map(other_thing, range(0,5))
    P.join()


def other_thing(arg):
    print(arg)
    return arg**2.

call_other_thing_with_multi()
```

When I call this, my code hangs at perpetuity. This is on windows with python 2.7.

Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.join), you need to call `close()` before `join()`:

```
import multiprocessing as multi

def call_other_thing_with_multi():
    P = multi.Pool(3)
    P.map(other_thing, range(0,5))
    P.close() # <-- calling close before P.join()
    P.join()
    print('END')

def other_thing(arg):
    print(arg)
    return arg**2.

call_other_thing_with_multi()
```

Prints:

```
0
1
2
3
4
END
```

EDIT: Better is use context manager, to not forget to call `close()`:

```
def call_other_thing_with_multi():
    with multi.Pool(3) as P:
        P.map(other_thing, range(0,5))
    print('END')
```

Comment: This actually also hangs

Comment: @jasonm Are you running exactly the same code? I'm on Python 3.6, but it shouldn't be a difference. I added version with context manager.

Comment: Yes running the same code. It does not work and the context does not work in py27 as indicated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25968518/python-multiprocessing-lib-error-attributeerror-exit

Comment: My question was poorly phrased and your solution indeed works.