# Simple multiprocessing Pool hangs in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to run some multiprocessing in a Jupyter notebook, using python version 3.7.0.
However, even a really simple example seems to hang indefinitely.
After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56780184/3752268) I tried explicitly calling .close and .join on the pool, but it still hangs. Example code is below, can anyone tell me what's wrong?

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def fun(x):
    return 2*x

with mp.Pool() as pool:
    args = list(range(10))
    res = pool.map(fun, args)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: `multiprocessing` has problems working in an interactive prompt. save your code as a .py file, and run it with the python interpreter. (it can be made to work, but it's much simpler to just run the file rather than execute code interactively)

Comment: If you look at the console where you started up Jupyter Notebook you will see a bunch of errors. You need to put function `fun` in an external file, for example, `workers.py` in the same directory as your ipynb file and then add `from workers import fun`. In other words, worker functions need to be imported.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jupyter notebook never finishes processing using multiprocessing (Python 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47313732/jupyter-notebook-never-finishes-processing-using-multiprocessing-python-3)

Answer (score 6):

Another solution is to use the `multiprocess` module, which is identical to the multiprocessing library while working with Jupyter.

Comment: This is the correct answer

Comment: Does not work for me - VS Code Jupyter / win 10 / Python 3.8.18. Above code hangs without an error on `pool.map()`. Also does not work with code as an external function....

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked the solution proposed by @Booboo.

- Write your function in an external file
- import it to your .ipynb file